# How to unprotect a route in API Pateform JWT Tokens

Tags: api, symfony

I've had the JWT Token library to my Api Plateform project.
The problem is that to register a user I need to have a JWT Token.
Or when a user want to create an account he cannot already have a token.

How can you deal with this issue in JWT protected api ?

I tried to change security.yaml configuration or check at the documentation but I haven't found anything that looked like my problem.